# iframe resize cause flickering when using different origin

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe

I need an advise on how to avoid iframe from flickering when resize.
I wanted to display bubble components within iframe when iframe is hovered. To display the bubble component, I would need to resize the iframe container.

The iframe source was built using react framework. So to pass the state change from iframe component to parent window, I'm doing it like this:

```
const onMouseOver = useCallback(() => {
  window.parent.postMessage({ isBubble: true }, '*');
}, [])
```

and in parent window, I'm listening to the state change like this:

```
// append iframe to parent window body
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = <source to my react web app>
iframe.style.width = '20px';
iframe.style.height = '20px';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

// listen to message
window.addEventListener('message', resizeIframe)

//resize iframe method
function resizeIframe(e) {
 var data = e.data

 // change iframe size 
 if (data.isBubble) {
  iframe.style.width = '100px';
  iframe.style.height = '100px';
 }
}
```

At first, I thought the flickering issue is because of iframe is not loaded properly.

I have tried all of the solution mentioned in [how to fix chrome flicker on iframe page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266753/how-to-fix-chrome-flicker-on-iframe-page-reload/22008377#22008377). But none of it is working.

I'm suspecting the flickering issue comes only when resize, cause when I used static iframe size, the bubble components popup properly without any issue.

edit: I found out the flickering issue happen only when i'm pointing iframe to different origin. Example `<iframe src="https://different origin"></iframe>`
but working fine if it is using same origin

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this library

> iframe-resizer-react

you can find it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/iframe-resizer-react

it should help with the problem that you are facing

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks ahmad for the suggestion, but i would prefer to know the root cause rather than using external library, plus the parent node is not build using react framework.

Comment: For the problem itself, I think that The event listener only updates on the end of onresize, then the session variable gets set, the tracker gets invalidated, which causes the context function to get rerun, which redraws the element.. Attaching to the onresizestart and onresizeend seems to help a tiny bit; but not much. Hope I helped!